# How to get metadata from asset url of photo

Tags: ios, metadata, photo, exif, alassetslibrary

I'm making a camera app for iOS that includes metadata for the photos.  I used the assetlibrary to write the metadata.  The method "writeImageDataToSavedPhotoAlbum" has a completion block that returns an asset URL.  I assume I need to save this URL so I can retrieve the metadata and image.  However, I can't seem to figure out what to do with the assetURL so that I get my information.

My code:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]){
    NSURL *urlOfVideo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
} else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {

    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *metadata = [self getGPSDictionaryForLocation:location];

    UIImage *theImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(theImage)];
    [library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:imageData metadata:metadata completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error");
        } else {

////what do I do with the assetURL?

            self.imageURL = assetURL;
            NSLog(@"url %@", self.imageURL);

        }
    } ];

}


[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load back the image using the ALAsset URL using the below code

```
 UIImage *myImage = nil;

 ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
 {

    CGImageRef iref = [myasset aspectRatioThumbnail];         

   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

       myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];

   });//end block


};
ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"Cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
};
NSURL *asseturl = //assign your ALAsset URL here
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturl 
               resultBlock:resultblock
              failureBlock:failureblock];
```